# Disable JQuery Mobile geolocation

Tags: jquery-mobile

Visiting any JQuery Mobile powered page with my iOS device seems to activate geolocation (the arrow appears on the upper right corner of Mobile Safari). The [JQuery Mobile site](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/) itself exhibiting this behavior. My application does not require geolocation, and it seems like a waste of battery.
How can I disable this geolocation ?

Comment: We're experiencing the very same problem, especially with the combination iOS6.1/iPhone5. Can't find any relevant code in jQuery's sources, must be a very strange bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like said in https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-mobile-activating-geolocation-on-mobile-devices it can be fixed by removing some code from jQueryMobile 1.2 (starting from line 846):

```
// DEPRECATED
if ( $.uiBackCompat !== false ) {
     $.Widget.prototype._getCreateOptions = function() {
         return $.metadata && $.metadata.get( this.element[0] )[ this.widgetName ];
    };
}
```

But I don't know why, yet....

Comment: Thanks. It appears this issue has now been covered to some extent, including there https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5378  with some explanation as to what was causing it